# retryWhen on RxJava with Rx2Apollo

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm using Rx2Apollo to make a graphql call:

```
private fun registerCardToken(token: String): io.reactivex.Observable<RegisterCardTokenMutation.RegisterCreditCard> {
    val apolloCall = apolloClient().mutate(RegisterCardTokenMutation.builder().token(token).build())
    return Rx2Apollo.from(apolloCall).map {
        (it.data() as RegisterCardTokenMutation.Data).registerCreditCard()
    }.doOnError({ error ->
        //Log.e("registerCardToke", error.message)
    })


}
```

This works well, but I want to handle specific error and retry this onces. I have tried to work around this using `retryWhen` and `retry` , but not able to write any executable code yet.

The retry persons a token refresh before performing the actual retry. Here's the token refresh sample:

```
private fun refreshBearerToken(callback: OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.getIdToken(true)?.addOnCompleteListener(callback)
    }
```

Comment: There exist an overload of [retry(Predicate)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#retry-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-) that let's you decide whether to retry for a particular exception or not.

Comment: @akarnokd any snippet or illustration  on doing that

Comment: @akarnokd , is there a way I can add a action before a retry, in my case, I did like to request for a new token and then perform a retry with that new token.

Comment: Where does that token come from?

Comment: @akarnokd , I just performed an edit

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to turn `refreshBearerToken` into an `Observable`

```
val refreshTokenSource = Observable.create({ emitter ->
    FirebaseAuth.
     getInstance().
     currentUser?.
     getIdToken(true)?.
     addOnCompleteListener({ task -> 
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             emitter.onNext(task.getResult())
             emitter.onComplete()
         } else {
             emitter.onError(task.getException())
         }
     }) 
})
```

Second, use some external reference holding the current token and conditionally use it before calling `registerCardToken`:

```
 val currentToken = AtomicReference<String>()

 val registerCardTokenObservable = Observable.defer({
     val token = currentToken.get()
     if (token == null) {
         return refreshTokenSource
            .doOnNext({ currentToken.set(it) })
            .flatMap({ registerCardToken(it) })
     }
     return registerCardToken(token)
 })
 .retry({ error -> 
     if ((error is IOException) || (error.getMessage().contains("network")) {
         currentToken.set(null)
         return true
     }
     return false
 })
```